# Get the sum of spend money per specific month

Tags: google-sheets, cost-management

I have months written out (January, February, ...) in D3:D and and the amount spent in F3:F, and want to show how much was spent in the specific months or basically if the condition "January" is met.

I tried using IF or COUNTIF but just don't understand the program well enough yet. I found =SUMIF($D$3:$D$1000, J3, $F$3:$F$1000) and =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(if($D$3:$D="January",$F$3:$F))) but those didn't work and show ERROR.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygLSb.png)

ChatGPT suggests =SUMIFS(F$3:F$100, D$3:D$100, "January")
but that also only shows an error message.

Comment: Without showing us some example data where you apply the formulae suggested with the errors shown as well, we have no idea what you might be doing wrong. Just as a first impression the sumif() looks fine with a range, criteria and sum_range, BUT without any data we cannot check.

Answer (score 0):

*Try using `semicolon convention`; You can find [some info here](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/) on syntax differences based on country setting*

```js
=sumif(D3:D;J3;E3:E)
```